# How to prove that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \pi|x-y|$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Question states

Prove that for all $x$ and $y\in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ the function $f(t) = \cos(t^2)$ satisfies the following inequality

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le \pi |x-y|.$$

Use the mean value theorem

So derivative of $\cos(t^2) = -2\sin(t)\cos(t) = - \sin(2t)$

so $ -\sin(2t) = \dfrac {\cos(x^2) - \cos(y^2)}{x-y}.$

$\sin(2t)$ is bounded by $1$ and $-1$ so $|f(x) - f(y)| \le |x-y|.$

I'm missing $\pi$ there, could you correct me?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt} \cos(t^2) = -2t\sin(t^2)$

Comment: This is $cos(t^2)$ rather than $(\cos(t))^2$. You computed the derivative of the second function  rather than the first one.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189)
I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is
possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: $$\cos(t^2)$$ is not $$-2\cos(t)\sin(t)$$!!!!!!!

Comment: wow my bad, thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it might be instructive to present a way forward that does not require use of calculus, but rather uses only standard trigonometry.  To that end, we proceed.

---

Using the [Prosthaphaeresis Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#Reverse_identities)

$$\cos(a)-\cos(b)=-2\sin\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{a-b}2\right)$$

along with the inequalities $|\sin(\theta)|\le |\theta|$ and $|\sin(\theta)|\le 1$, we find with $a=x^2$ and $b=y^2$

$$\begin{align}
|\cos(x^2)-\cos(y^2)|&=2\left|\sin\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{x^2-y^2}2\right)\right|\\\\
&\le |x^2-y^2|\\\\
&=|x+y|\,|x-y|\\\\
&\le \pi |x-y|
\end{align}$$

since for $x,y\in (0,\pi/2)$, $0\le x+y\le \pi$.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=-\sin(\xi^2)2\xi$$